# Excel Data Connection Keep original formatting from other workbook

Tags: excel

In an excel workbook, called workbook A, I set up a connection to another workbook, called workbook B for one particular spreadsheet. This is because I need the worksheet in both locations, and for it to update in the background. That is all set up and working fine, however I want to keep the original formatting. Ive searched the web and tried editing the 'Data' External Data Properties, preserving the cell formatting is enabled. However the data displaying is not in correct format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Paste twice is required.

1) Paste link
2) Paste format

See link below:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/500227-how-do-i-paste-links-and-keep-formats.html